# TypeError on Firebase function for letting users sign up

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am new to React Native and Firebase. I have been following a [YouTube tutorial on coding an Instagram clone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hPgQWbWmEk) and cannot get my code working. I get a type error as described in the title from the onSignUp() method and the line of code calling the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function. The entire app crashes after the error. I did have to change the import statements from what the tutorial had since the way of importing Firebase has become outdated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native'

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
require('firebase/auth')
export class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            name: ''
        }

        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
    }

    onSignUp() {
        const { email, password, name } = this.state;
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="name"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                />
                <Button 
                    onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                    title="Sign Up"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Register
```

Comment: what is the type error??

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.default.auth is not a function

Comment: You imported something that doesn't have an auth() function. Try to find the docs from firebase for your version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
```